# How to make File Explorer always show the same view for all folders (windows10)?

Tags: windows-10

Today I'm doing work that needs sort-by-type. Every single time I change folder, I have to re-sort that folder by type.

Tomororow, when I'm looking for a file by name ... Every single time I change folder, I'll have to re-sort that folder *AGAIN*.

The "make everything have the same default" hacks (various great question/answers here on SU) solved half the problem, but to make them work in Windows10 (which has a really stupid "if I see a folder full of e.g. .MP3 files, I will force you to view them in a terrible way" set of design mistakes) seems to force Windows10 to fallback on making every folder unique, and wiping your settings continuously while using it.

TL;DR: all I want is a file explorer that - while I'm using it - carries on working as it's been told to; not continuously trying to change every time I click on a folder :)

Answer (score -3):

### Procedure:

- Open a folder. Set the Folder View as wish. This will be our template view for
  all folder.
- Now click on the upper row aka. menu bar, choose "View" > "Options".
  Like this following image:

[image: explorer-view-option]

- It opens "Folder Options" window. Choose "View" tab > "Apply to Folders".
  Like this following image:

[image: folder-options-window]

- Optionally, Restart File Explorer or logout and re-login.

Comment: This does not answer any part of the question, I'm afraid. The question starts AFTER having done everything you've described here.